# Error setting php version for azure windows web app terraform

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, terraform-provider-azure

I'm deploying a web app service to Azure via terraform. My runtime stack should be php. The [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app) states the `php_version` variable should be "v7.4". Within my github actions run, I receive the below error:

```
[ERROR] vertex "azurerm_windows_web_app.lab9_app_srv" 
error: expected site_config.0.application_stack.0.php_version to be one of [7.4], got v7.4
```

Terraform version used in deployment: `~>3.30.0`

I understand that the [end of life for php version 7.4](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/community-support-for-php-74-is-ending-on-28-november-2022/) is 28/11/2022, but version 8.0 is not set as an option in the terraform documentation.

I changed the php_version variable to the below assignments to no avail:

- `php_version=["7.4"]`
- `php_version=["v7.4"]`
- `php_version=7.4`

When the php_version was declared in a list, the below error is produced:

`Inappropriate value for attribute "php_version": string required.`

The `web-app.tf` config deploys the web app resource as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "lab9_app_srv" {
    name                = "${local.naming_prefix}wapp-service-${random_integer.rand_val.result}"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.lab9_resource_group.name
    location            = azurerm_service_plan.lab9_app_srv_plan.location
    service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.lab9_app_srv_plan.id

    # ensuring web app is enabled 
    enabled = true

    site_config {
        # ensuring web app is always on 
        always_on = true
        
        application_stack {
            current_stack = "php"
            # PHP 7.4 will reach EOL on 30/11/2022
            # https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/tree/master/Runtime_Support
            php_version = ["7.4"]
        }
    }

    # explicit dependancy set on creation of app service plan 
    depends_on = [
      azurerm_service_plan.lab9_app_srv_plan
    ]
}
```

Any advice on how to properly declare the php_version I want to use? If I am not mistaken, this seems to be just a syntactical error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says that the property `php_version` accepts string type input. You just need to pass the value of `php_verion` as "7.4" or "8.0".

I have tested this in my local environment and able to deploy the phpv8.0 webapp without any issues.

**Here is my terraform script that I have tested:**

[image]

**Here is the sample output for your reference:**

[image]

**Note**: Starting from php8.0 is supported only for Linux app service plan refer to [this documentation](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/php_support.md#php-8) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @VenkateshDodda-MSFT "7.4" instead of what the documentation states: "v7.4", did the trick for me.

Comment: @ZimCanIT - Glad to know that issue got resolved :)

Comment: Btw, a pull request was made for hashicorp to update php versions so that they match the portal versions; if you could please support the pr:  https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/19440